# Can't get over ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Hello I'm trying to learn Rails and I follow this tutorial -> http://vimeo.com/10732081 which explains how to build a blog page. I use Rails 4.1 and the PostsController is:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html
  def index
    @posts = Post.order("created_at desc")
    respond_with @posts
  end

  def create
    Post.create(params[:post])
    redirect_to posts_path
  end

end
```

When I create a new post, using this .erb page:

```
<h1>Create a new post</h1>
<%= form_for Post.new do |form| %>
<%= form.text_field :title %>
<%= form.text_area :body %>
<%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

it throws the ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

After googling (including the pages from Stackoverflow) I found that addition of something like

```
params.permit post: [:title, :body]
```

was necessary, but it's uncertain where to put this method and which parameters should be used. It looks like all of the answers suppose I know Ruby and Rails already but I don't, I'm a newbie. I need help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
# app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
def create
  Post.create(post_params)
  redirect_to posts_path
end

private

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the input. I've tried it but it throws the same error message. It's almost like Ruby interpreter doesn't even care what's being written after or before that 'create' method. Btw, the error message being thrown is: [link]http://i.hizliresim.com/bQp7Ed.png

Comment: The error message shown is using your original code. Can you show the exact error message when using the code as I wrote it in my answer? I'll take a look and see if I spot anything. :)

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I've checked with the code and re-edited it and now it correctly contains the code you've given. Here it is: http://i.hizliresim.com/WWR2Em.png but it still gives the same error.

I 've opened the code to Internet at http://ipkullan.com:3001/posts/new  You can check it out. Thanks.

Comment: Try replacing `Post.create(params[:post])` with `Post.create(post_params)`

Comment: Thank you for the comment. After the replacement, it finally worked. That's nice but one more question: is the post_params a variable or a function here. I think or  it looks to be a function, is that correct? Thanks.

Comment: It's a function, more commonly called a `method` in Ruby. You can tell it is a method because you defined it with syntax like `def post_params...`. A variable would be defined differently, like this: `post_params = ...`